# Spliting a HUGE CSV File with Powershell into chunks

Tags: powershell

So I have several CSV files that are more than 1 million lines of data.
I would like to split these into 50,000 line chunks or so into a new csv file.

I used line reader In powershell to read the lines, but I'm trying to figure out the export part of it, which I keep pushing out errors.

```
$PSScriptRoot

write-host $PSScriptRoot

$loc = $PSScriptRoot

$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($loc + "/import/Split.csv")
try {
    for() {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if ($line -eq $null) { break }
        # process the line
        $line
    }
}
finally {
    $reader.Close()
}
```

Comment: [1] what errors? [*grin*] ///// [2] there is no `for()` in PoSh that i know of. what is that?

Comment: So this works, as it basically is just writing the lines down and displaying them in the shell. But if I tried to build a counter and export them, it throws memory issues.

Comment: https://www.spjeff.com/2017/06/02/powershell-split-csv-in-1000-line-batches/

Comment: the following reddit thread shows two ways to split a large CSV file - [1] use `Get-Content -ReadCount 1000`. ///// [2] use the streamreader stuff from dotnet to read in lines & then write them out. ///// Parse VERY LARGE CSV : PowerShell — https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/8zwyof/parse_very_large_csv/

Comment: Thank you LEe, I looked that over, but that is for parsing a file, I need to have create a new file every 10,000 rows or so and continue.

Comment: You're going to have to read the file to write out the chunks. Lee_Dailey has most of it from his link, check the top reply from Beablebeable. You just need to take the content read and start creating the new files.